# Looking for a cursive font like D'Nealian Cursive

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

Back in elementary and middle school, the form of cursive I learned was D'Nealian Cursive. Although my handwriting has changed from it (e.g. more flowing uppercase ar and pee), I still find it like a standard. Does such a font or a similar one exist that I may use on my computer?

Update: Here's a [screenshot](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/Cursive.svg).

[image]

Comment: Do you mind making an edit with the font you are referring to so we can provide you with an accurate answer?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.schoolfonts.com/ sells the official d'nealian cursive font. They also have a free demo version of the font.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is just what I was looking for. They even have the different style of cue I use!